# Having Multiple icons on the taskbar for most IDE

Tags: ide, taskbar

For most IDE, such as eclipse, Intellij, Processing, and other, it seems that even after pinning the program to the task bar, when I actually open it, it creates another program that is not pinned to the task bar. As a result, I have multiple icons on the taskbar. I'm guessing that the ones I pinned on the taskbars are kind of like launching applications and they open a separate application, not that I'm sure of this theory, but I'd prefer to have only one application showing up on the taskbar. So, is there a way to set it up so even after I start the program, another doesn't show up on the taskbar? 
Also, It seems like I can't pin the program that gets opened.
Here's a picture of the taskbar.
Or, since it seems like I can't post a picture yet, 
This is what's going on with my taskbar.
http://i1320.photobucket.com/albums/u538/jerichoi224/Untitled_zps216034f9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because IDEs launch instances, which Windows doesn't support taskbar pinning for.

The solution for Eclipse IDE is to add:

```
-vm
C:/path_to_jre/bin
```

, to the beginning of the eclipse.ini file, in the eclipse directory, and relaunching the IDE.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any solutions for other programs?

Comment: @jerichoi224 - The IntelliJ suite of IDEs are pinnable out-of-the-box for me. I don't have any experience with the Processing IDE.